# Using VBA to update cells in one sheet based on match in second sheet

Tags: vba, excel

So this is my first attempt at my own code. Up to now I have always found something that leads me in the right direction but am stuck here. I commented the code below to show what I am trying to do but it fails miserably. Any help is certainly appreciated.

```
Sub Update_Hours()

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws1_employee, ws2_employee As String
Dim ws1_lastrow, ws2_lastrow, currenthours, latesthours, newhours As Long
Dim ws1_counter, ws2_counter As Integer

Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Current Hours")
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Latest Hours")

With ws1
    ws1_lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row in the Current Hours sheet
End With


With ws2
    ws1_lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row in the Latest Hours sheet
End With

For ws1_counter = 2 To ws1_lastrow 'Loop through all values in column A on Current Hours sheet

    ws1_employee = ws1.Cells("A" & ws1_counter).Value
    Set currenthours = ws1.Cells("F" & ws1_counter).Value

    For ws2_counter = 2 To ws2_lastrow 'Loop through all values in column A on Latest Hours sheet

        ws2_employee = ws2.Cells("A" & ws2_counter).Value

        If ws1_employee = ws2_employee Then 'Check for a match between the two employee names

            latesthours = ws2.Cells("C" & ws2_counter).Value
            newhours = latesthours + currenthours
            ws1.Cells("F" & ws1_counter).Value = newhours 'Update the cell in the Current Hours sheet with the new total hours

        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: you made a typo and wrote `ws1_lastrow` instead of `ws2_lastrow` after `with ws2`, I think. And when you define variable, you have to explicit the type for each one, not just for the last of the line (in your case for example, ws1 is a variant, while ws2 is a worksheet, same for the other lines)

Comment: Seems to me this can be done with a SUMIF() equation: `=SUMIF('Latest Hours'!A:A,A2,'Latest Hours'!C:C)` in F2 on `Current Hours` then copy/drag down.

Comment: hi and thanks for that. i indeed made a typo. now that i have the variables defined properly it hangs when i try to set one of those variables to a value in the cell so the line: "ws1_employee = ws1.Cells("A" & ws1_counter).Value"

Comment: The .Cells expects numeric inputs, it looks like you want to use .Range in place of .cells.  Otherwise, you could change to
"ws1_employee = ws1.Cells(ws1_counter, 1).Value"

Comment: Thanks for the help. Changed to range, fixed the typo, all is good. Realised i had misdeclared the hours so had to change that to a variant but now works great